# What is image name?

Tags: windows-7

What exactly is image name? For example,

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq myapp.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "myapp.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo Programm is running
```

I googled can't seem to find its definition anywhere. Why is it called image name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image name is the name of the executable, e.g. explorer.exe or myapp.exe, so you're already using it correctly. /FI is similar to find, so find is only useful if you need the errorlevel.